# Why does my character glitch out when i put it on a path

Tags: animation

[video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GqzU.jpg)   [blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bI0e4TdFeO4cYByZfOrOnUYtgAHvnx_L)

i animated my character and when i put it on a path to walk it glitches out and distorts. At first i tried just moving it with g and it did the same thing and now im trying to put it on a path and it does the same thing. Ive linked a blend file and a video file. If any of you could help me it would be appreiated

Comment: In these cases I usually parent the character's main armature to what I call a 
'Nav(igation) Empty'.  The character is then moved around by dragging that. This makes the armature's keyframes relative to the Nav-empty and insulates the walking action from the path's function - i.e. turn and move the character along the path. My preference is to use another Empty on the path itself and get that moving as required, then parent the character's Nav-Empty to the path Empty.  See next...

Comment: Continuing from above ... Whilst sounding a little cumbersome this approach makes things a lot easier when a character is to approach and enter a path (or any other constraint for that matter) and once traversed, leave the path and continue on using keyframes once more.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the following one:

You're trying to give a *Follow Path* constraint to your mesh, but it's not the thing to do, it's not the mesh that is supposed to follow the path, the mesh is parented to the armature, it's the armature that is supposed to follow the path... If you give your mesh a *Follow Path* constraint, it has 2 contradictory constraints: The *Follow Path* and the armature, and it can't work.

So give the *Follow Path* to the armature.

Also, you need to make sure that you've:

- Applied the scale and rotation of your curve.
- Given it the right direction, i.e. the direction that the armature is supposed to follow, in *Edit* mode switch it with a <kbd>W</kbd> > *Switch Direction*.
- Put the curve origin at its beginning.
- Put the armature at the center of the scene with an <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, so that it sticks to the beginning of the curve once you create the *Follow Path*.

But it looks already good...